# Strange behaviours of the String's contains and replaceAll methods with special characters

Tags: java, string, replaceall, contain

I did a little research with the String's contains and replaceAll methods.

```
char c = '*';

String str = "1220"+c+""+c+""+c+""+c+""+c+"23";
System.out.println(str.contains(c+""));
System.out.println(str.contains("["+c+"]"));
System.out.println(str.contains("\\"+c));


System.out.println(str.replaceAll("["+c+"]", "X"));
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\"+c, "X"));
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(c+"", "X"));
```

Results : 
When c = '*' or '^' or '+'

```
true
false
false
1220XXXXX23
1220XXXXX23
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException
```

When c = '#' or '~' or '%' or '<' or '>' or '=' or '&' or '@' or '-' or '!'

```
true
false
false
1220XXXXX23
1220XXXXX23
1220XXXXX23
```

When c = '$'

```
true
false
false
1220XXXXX23
1220XXXXX23
1220$$$$$23X
```

when c = '|'

```
true
false
false
1220XXXXX23
1220XXXXX23
X1X2X2X0X|X|X|X|X|X2X3X
```

I am wondering about what is the theory / rule behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of `contains` and the first argument of `replaceAll` are *interpreted* differently: the former is just a character sequence, while the later is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Since `*` is a *meta-character* of the Java's regexp language that cannot appear unescaped on its own (it must follow an expression being repeated zero or more times in the match), it is treated differently by the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

str.replaceAll(...) uses **regular expression** as first argument.
Characters *,$,^,+,? and others are part of **regular expression** syntax. See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for details about how they are treated by replaceAll.